# Socket.io Private Message in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am listing users from users array with socket io .İf ı click username modal will open and send message to ı clicked user.

Here server side:

```
socket.on('privatemessage', function(data){
    if (data == "" || data == undefined) {
        socket.emit('alert',{
            value:"write a message"
        });
    }
    else {
        if (socket.nick in users) {
            socket.in(socket.nick).emit('sendmessage', socket.name, data);
        } else {
            console.log('message not send');
        }
    }
});
socket.on('username', function(nick){
    socket.nick=nick;
    socket.emit('updatemodal', nick);
});
```

socket.nick is ı clicked user.

And client side:

```
socket.on('sendmessage', function(name, data){
output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + name + ' :</strong>' + data + '</p>';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
});
```

Modal;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalpencere">
                    <div id="output"></div>
                    <div id="modalfeedback"></div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" style="resize: vertical;" id="modalmesaj" class="form-control" placeholder="Mesaj">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" id="modalgonder" class="btn btn-primary">Gönder<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" id="modalcikis" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Çıkış</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I updated post.Pls help me.

Comment: Where is the modal part?

Comment: I updated post.

Comment: @C0dekid I added the modal part

Comment: What is the variable 'output'? Why is your modal function in a doc ready, inside of a socket receive function?

Comment: Place where output will appear

Comment: have you got result?